# AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, pillow

```
from PIL import ImageFilter

im1 = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

при использовании данной строчки в коде выдаёт ошибку

```
"AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'filter'"
```

хотя эта строчка скопирована с официальной документации Pillow.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в документации не написано, что метод `filter` есть у класса `PhotoImage`, а вы пытаетесь его использовать.

А перед кодом, который вы используете сказано следующее:

> The ImageFilter module contains definitions for a pre-defined set of filters, which can be be used with the Image.filter() method.

Используем переводчик и получаем:

> Модуль ImageFilter содержит определения для заранее определенного набора фильтров, которые можно использовать с помощью метода Image.filter().